# Example of E(E(X|F)|G) \neq E(E(X|G)|F)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Can you find an example where 
 E(E(X|F)|G) $\neq$ E(E(X|G)|F) (F and G is $\sigma$-field in probability theory)

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try an example with $F$ and $G$ the $\sigma$-algebras generated by random variables $Y,Z$
respectively. $\mathbb E[\ldots|F]$ is a function of $Y$ and $\mathbb E[\ldots|G]$ is a function of $Z$.  Except in "trivial" cases, these won't be equal.